# Spark Structured Streaming takes too much time to compute aggregated query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm running a simple Spark Structured Streaming (V 2.2.0) program that reads a small amount of data from Kafka and performs some aggregated query on them (with 'update' output mode). However, my program gets stuck for a long time after printing out the result of one or two batches in the console. (I tried it so many times and developed my program both in Scala and Python). For instance, in the following example, when it got stuck, I stopped the program that was feeding Kafka, instantly, and then after 5 minutes, Spark Streaming continued to work. Can anybody understand why Spark Structured Streaming cannot even handle a very small amount of data?

I ran Zookeeper and Kafka (V 0.11.0.0) on the same machine (MacBook Pro 15-inch, Mid 2015) with default configurations and fed Kafka with only 5 strings (each maximum 100 chars) per second.

Here is the Spark Structured Streaming code in Scala:

```scala
  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("StructuredNetworkFeatureExtractor")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val input = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "mytopic")
    .load

  val result = input.withColumn("_tmp", split($"value", ",")).select(
    $"_tmp".getItem(0).as("src_ip"),
    $"_tmp".getItem(1).as("dst_ip"),
    $"_tmp".getItem(2).as("dst_port"),
    $"_tmp".getItem(3).as("protocol"),
    $"_tmp".getItem(4).as("start_time"),
    $"_tmp".getItem(5).as("end_time"),
    $"_tmp".getItem(6).as("packets")
  ).drop("_tmp").groupBy("src_ip", "dst_ip", "dst_port", "protocol").count()

  val query = result.writeStream
    .outputMode("update")
    .format("console")
    .start()

  query.awaitTermination()
```

The program is working well with 'append' output mode and also in the first one or two batches of 'update' output mode.

These are a few Spark Streaming logs before getting stuck:

```
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 186.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 605) in 43 ms on localhost (executor driver) (186/200)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO Executor: Running task 193.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 612)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Retrieved version 2 of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=192), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/192] for update
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Retrieved version 2 of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=192), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/192] for update
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 1 blocks
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Retrieved version 2 of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=193), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/193] for update
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Retrieved version 2 of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=193), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/193] for update
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 1 blocks
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Committed version 3 for HDFSStateStore[id = (op=0, part=189), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/189] to file checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/189/3.delta
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO Executor: Finished task 189.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 608). 3952 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 194.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 613, localhost, executor driver, partition 194, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6685 bytes)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO Executor: Running task 194.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 613)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 189.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 608) in 38 ms on localhost (executor driver) (187/200)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Committed version 3 for HDFSStateStore[id = (op=0, part=190), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/190] to file checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/190/3.delta
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Retrieved version 2 of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=194), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/194] for update
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Retrieved version 2 of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=194), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/194] for update
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 1 blocks
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO Executor: Finished task 190.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 609). 3952 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 195.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 614, localhost, executor driver, partition 195, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6685 bytes)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO Executor: Running task 195.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 614)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 190.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 609) in 33 ms on localhost (executor driver) (188/200)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Committed version 3 for HDFSStateStore[id = (op=0, part=191), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/191] to file checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/191/3.delta
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Retrieved version 2 of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=195), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/195] for update
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Retrieved version 2 of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=195), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/195] for update
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 1 blocks
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO Executor: Finished task 191.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 610). 3952 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 196.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 615, localhost, executor driver, partition 196, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6685 bytes)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 191.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 610) in 16 ms on localhost (executor driver) (189/200)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO Executor: Running task 196.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 615)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Committed version 3 for HDFSStateStore[id = (op=0, part=192), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/192] to file checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/192/3.delta
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Committed version 3 for HDFSStateStore[id = (op=0, part=193), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/193] to file checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/193/3.delta
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO Executor: Finished task 192.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 611). 3952 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO Executor: Finished task 193.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 612). 3952 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 197.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 616, localhost, executor driver, partition 197, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6685 bytes)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO Executor: Running task 197.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 616)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 198.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 617, localhost, executor driver, partition 198, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6685 bytes)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 192.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 611) in 16 ms on localhost (executor driver) (190/200)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO Executor: Running task 198.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 617)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 193.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 612) in 14 ms on localhost (executor driver) (191/200)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Retrieved version 2 of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=196), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/196] for update
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Retrieved version 2 of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=196), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/196] for update
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 1 blocks
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Retrieved version 2 of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=198), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/198] for update
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Retrieved version 2 of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=198), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/198] for update
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Retrieved version 2 of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=197), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/197] for update
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 1 blocks
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Retrieved version 2 of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=197), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/197] for update
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 1 blocks
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Committed version 3 for HDFSStateStore[id = (op=0, part=194), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/194] to file checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/194/3.delta
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO Executor: Finished task 194.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 613). 3952 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 199.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 618, localhost, executor driver, partition 199, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6685 bytes)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 194.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 613) in 15 ms on localhost (executor driver) (192/200)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO Executor: Running task 199.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 618)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Committed version 3 for HDFSStateStore[id = (op=0, part=195), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/195] to file checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/195/3.delta
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO Executor: Finished task 195.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 614). 3952 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 195.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 614) in 16 ms on localhost (executor driver) (193/200)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Retrieved version 2 of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=199), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/199] for update
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Retrieved version 2 of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=199), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/199] for update
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 1 blocks
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Committed version 3 for HDFSStateStore[id = (op=0, part=197), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/197] to file checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/197/3.delta
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Committed version 3 for HDFSStateStore[id = (op=0, part=196), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/196] to file checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/196/3.delta
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Committed version 3 for HDFSStateStore[id = (op=0, part=198), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/198] to file checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/198/3.delta
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO Executor: Finished task 196.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 615). 3952 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO Executor: Finished task 197.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 616). 3952 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO Executor: Finished task 198.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 617). 3952 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 196.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 615) in 17 ms on localhost (executor driver) (194/200)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 197.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 616) in 15 ms on localhost (executor driver) (195/200)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 198.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 617) in 15 ms on localhost (executor driver) (196/200)
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Committed version 3 for HDFSStateStore[id = (op=0, part=199), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/199] to file checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/199/3.delta
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO Executor: Finished task 199.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 618). 3952 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:41:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 199.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 618) in 15 ms on localhost (executor driver) (197/200)
```

It got stuck at 12:41:08 and after 5 minutes continued:

```
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Committed version 3 for HDFSStateStore[id = (op=0, part=77), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/77] to file checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/77/3.delta
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Committed version 3 for HDFSStateStore[id = (op=0, part=27), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/27] to file checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/27/3.delta
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Finished task 77.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 496). 4025 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Finished task 27.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 446). 4116 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 77.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 496) in 300007 ms on localhost (executor driver) (198/200)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 27.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 446) in 300649 ms on localhost (executor driver) (199/200)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: Committed version 3 for HDFSStateStore[id = (op=0, part=78), dir = checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/78] to file checkpoint/8cc5a2fc-4245-40ef-a66f-113d42abc50c/state/0/78/3.delta
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Finished task 78.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 497). 4025 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 78.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 497) in 300012 ms on localhost (executor driver) (200/200)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 11.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 11 (start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97) finished in 302.767 s
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 8 finished: start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97, took 302.903295 s
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 9 (start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97) with 1 output partitions
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 12 (start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 12 (MapPartitionsRDD[47] at start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97), which has no missing parents
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_18 stored as values in memory (estimated size 9.6 KB, free 2003.5 MB)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_18_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.8 KB, free 2003.5 MB)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_18_piece0 in memory on 10.249.202.140:50853 (size: 4.8 KB, free: 2004.4 MB)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 18 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 12 (MapPartitionsRDD[47] at start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 12.0 with 1 tasks
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 619, localhost, executor driver, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7995 bytes)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 619)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 619). 1304 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 619) in 5 ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/1)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 12.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 12 (start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97) finished in 0.005 s
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 9 finished: start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97, took 0.010624 s
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 10 (start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97) with 4 output partitions
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 13 (start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 13 (MapPartitionsRDD[47] at start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97), which has no missing parents
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_19 stored as values in memory (estimated size 9.6 KB, free 2003.5 MB)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_19_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.8 KB, free 2003.5 MB)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_19_piece0 in memory on 10.249.202.140:50853 (size: 4.8 KB, free: 2004.4 MB)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 19 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 4 missing tasks from ResultStage 13 (MapPartitionsRDD[47] at start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 13.0 with 4 tasks
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 620, localhost, executor driver, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7995 bytes)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 621, localhost, executor driver, partition 2, PROCESS_LOCAL, 8000 bytes)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 622, localhost, executor driver, partition 3, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7997 bytes)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 623, localhost, executor driver, partition 4, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7987 bytes)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 620)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 621)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 622)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Running task 3.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 623)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 620). 1289 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 621). 1305 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Finished task 3.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 623). 1297 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 622). 1308 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 620) in 4 ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/4)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 3.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 623) in 4 ms on localhost (executor driver) (2/4)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 621) in 4 ms on localhost (executor driver) (3/4)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 622) in 4 ms on localhost (executor driver) (4/4)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 13.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 13 (start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97) finished in 0.005 s
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 10 finished: start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97, took 0.006888 s
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 11 (start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97) with 3 output partitions
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 14 (start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 14 (MapPartitionsRDD[47] at start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97), which has no missing parents
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_20 stored as values in memory (estimated size 9.6 KB, free 2003.5 MB)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_20_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.8 KB, free 2003.5 MB)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_20_piece0 in memory on 10.249.202.140:50853 (size: 4.8 KB, free: 2004.4 MB)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 20 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 3 missing tasks from ResultStage 14 (MapPartitionsRDD[47] at start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 14.0 with 3 tasks
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 624, localhost, executor driver, partition 5, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7993 bytes)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 625, localhost, executor driver, partition 6, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7994 bytes)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 626, localhost, executor driver, partition 7, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7992 bytes)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 624)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 625)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 626)

17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 625). 1298 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 624). 1298 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 626). 1312 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 625) in 3 ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/3)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 624) in 4 ms on localhost (executor driver) (2/3)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 626) in 3 ms on localhost (executor driver) (3/3)
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 14.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 14 (start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97) finished in 0.004 s
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 11 finished: start at FeatureExtractor.scala:97, took 0.008861 s
17/08/15 12:46:07 INFO StreamExecution: Streaming query made progress: {
  "id" : "c84a0d40-ac3e-4a55-98c4-c63c14abcc12",
  "runId" : "ddadecb7-b3b9-4c1b-b742-90638b43e5a0",
  "name" : null,
  "timestamp" : "2017-08-15T19:41:03.971Z",
  "numInputRows" : 20,
  "inputRowsPerSecond" : 4.163197335553705,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.06597459318416478,
  "durationMs" : {
    "addBatch" : 303093,
    "getBatch" : 4,
    "getOffset" : 1,
    "queryPlanning" : 12,
    "triggerExecution" : 303147,
    "walCommit" : 32
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ {
    "numRowsTotal" : 28,
    "numRowsUpdated" : 16
  } ],
  "sources" : [ {
    "description" : "KafkaSource[Subscribe[mytopic]]",
    "startOffset" : {
      "mytopic" : {
        "0" : 101830
      }
    },
    "endOffset" : {
      "mytopic" : {
        "0" : 101850
      }
    },
    "numInputRows" : 20,
    "inputRowsPerSecond" : 4.163197335553705,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.06597459318416478
  } ],
  "sink" : {
    "description" : "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ConsoleSink@6ceb7741"
  }
}
```

These are also the logs of Kafka (in console) at the same time:

```
[2017-08-15 12:40:54,327] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to rebalance group spark-kafka-source-d7625848-02f2-4af7-9285-1ddd2b0906cf-1499473642-driver-0 with old generation 0 (__consumer_offsets-6) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2017-08-15 12:40:54,328] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Stabilized group spark-kafka-source-d7625848-02f2-4af7-9285-1ddd2b0906cf-1499473642-driver-0 generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-6) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2017-08-15 12:40:54,334] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Assignment received from leader for group spark-kafka-source-d7625848-02f2-4af7-9285-1ddd2b0906cf-1499473642-driver-0 for generation 1 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2017-08-15 12:40:54,335] INFO Updated PartitionLeaderEpoch. New: {epoch:0, offset:0}, Current: {epoch:-1, offset-1} for Partition: __consumer_offsets-6. Cache now contains 0 entries. (kafka.server.epoch.LeaderEpochFileCache)
[2017-08-15 12:43:08,939] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2017-08-15 12:46:03,978] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to rebalance group spark-kafka-source-d7625848-02f2-4af7-9285-1ddd2b0906cf-1499473642-driver-0 with old generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-6) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2017-08-15 12:46:03,980] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Group spark-kafka-source-d7625848-02f2-4af7-9285-1ddd2b0906cf-1499473642-driver-0 with generation 2 is now empty (__consumer_offsets-6) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2017-08-15 12:46:07,120] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to rebalance group spark-kafka-source-d7625848-02f2-4af7-9285-1ddd2b0906cf-1499473642-driver-0 with old generation 2 (__consumer_offsets-6) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2017-08-15 12:46:07,122] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Stabilized group spark-kafka-source-d7625848-02f2-4af7-9285-1ddd2b0906cf-1499473642-driver-0 generation 3 (__consumer_offsets-6) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

**UPDATE:**

I looked at the Spark application UI and it seems that the time-consuming part is the "Executor Computing Time" of a few tasks.

[image: Spark application UI]

Comment: Did you manage to solve these performance issues? I am experiencing a similar situation

Comment: @GiselleVanDongen I remember I tried exactly the same thing with another laptop and it worked correctly. So I thought maybe there was an issue with the laptop. I didn't actually end up understanding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your are shuffling a lot, try partitioning your kafka stream and use partition key for aggregation. Just an idea not an answer.

Comment: I added another part to my question. It seems that it's because of Executor Computing Time, not the shuffling read and write time.